# CMake For Google Tests When Class Definitions Are In .CPP

Tags: c++, unit-testing, class, cmake, googletest

When my class definitions are inside my .h files, my make command did not give any errors and my tests were passing successfully.

However, as soon as I move the class definitions to .cpp files, I get an `` undefined reference to `Class::method(int)' `` for everything. How should I change my CMakeLists.txt accordingly?

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

I have followed this tutorial:

https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/

Example. Instructor.h

```
#ifndef INSTRUCTOR_H
#define INSTRUCTOR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Instructor
{
    int instrId;
    string instrEmail;
    string instrPassword;

public:
    Instructor();
    void showGameStatus();
    void setInstrId(int newInstrId);
    int getInstrId();

};

#endif
```

Instructor.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Instructor.h"
using namespace std;

Instructor::Instructor()
{
    cout << " Default Instructor Constructor\n";
    instrId = 0;
    instrEmail = "@jaocbs-university.de";
    instrPassword = "123";
}
void Instructor::setInstrId(const int newInstrId)
{
     instrId = newInstrId;
}

int Instructor::getInstrId()
{
    return instrId;
}
```

Comment: Why are you moving them to the `.cpp` file instead of keeping them in a header file where it's easier for the test to access them? If you need to test the code you need to have it accessible outside of the `.cpp` file, which means you need a header.

Comment: isn't it recommended to have class definitions and declarations in separate files? At least that's what I learnt in school. I edited the qs with an example of what I meant, in case it wasn't clear @tadman

Comment: Your example makes things a lot more clear now. I misconstrued "definitions" as in "declarations" with "definitions" as in "implementations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting "undefined reference" of that sort make sure you're linking in the result of compiling `Instructor.cpp`, or that `Instructor.cpp` is a dependency of the test depending on how your build is organized.

This may be as simple as:

```
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp Instructor.cpp)
```

Though that may need to be adjusted based on the specifics of your path.